# Gradle sync failed - Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Android Gradle Sync Failed to Sync project:

```
Cause: org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I'm using Android Studio 4.0

[image]